# Convert generic type using stream

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am particularly interested in opportunities of doing this:

```
List<Object> a = new ...
List<Integer> b = (List<Integer>) a;
```

My objects will return int after `Integer.parseInt(object.toString());`
I want downcating, I remember it impossible by some reason. Could you remind me reason, please. Could you show me the most sophisticated way of convention using tools of Java 8.

Comment: It's impossible because a `List<Object>` is not a `List<Integer>` (nor vice versa).

Comment: @PaulBoddington, thanks I got it. List is List and there is nothing to cast. Will delete the question.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(object.toString());` looks like trying to fit a square box in a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new list.

```
List<Integer> b = a.stream()
                   .map(Object::toString)
                   .map(Integer::parseInt)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(This has nothing to do with downcasting).

Comment: `Integer::valueOf` gives you back the already boxed version of `int`.

Comment: @Flown True. I would use `Integer::valueOf` too but I wrote `parseInt` to match the question.